# Error while creating a Document variable with a XML parser in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, netbeans

lately i've been gettin an error while running my code

I'm using this code to create the Document file

---

```
DocumentBuilderFactory bFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

DocumentBuilder dBuilder = bFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = (Document) dBuilder.parse(xmlfile);
```

---

And i'm getting this error

---

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl cannot be
>   cast to javax.swing.text.Document     at rss.RSS.main(RSS.java:72)
>
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1
>
> BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

---

I'm not very familiar with programming but i've got a task to do. I would be glad if you could help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the import being used for the following line is `javax.swing.text.Document`:

```
Document doc = (Document) dBuilder.parse(xmlfile);
```

One possible explanation is that your source file is using both of the following two classes:

```
javax.swing.text.Document
org.w3c.dom.Document
```

This explanation would make sense if you are trying to do both Swing and XML dom stuff in the same source file.  A workaround is to use the fully qualified class name here, e.g.

```
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = (org.w3c.dom.Document) dBuilder.parse(xmlfile);
```

Note that you *could* also make `org.w3c.dom.Document` the primary import and then use `javax.swing.text.Document` everywhere for the Swing document class.  In practice, you would probably want to be consistent everywhere, i.e. use fully qualified for all Swing or for all `org.w3c.dom` classes.  And which class is used to most might be what you choose to import, which would free you from having to type package names the most.

Comment: It worked very well for me thank you very much! But i'm also getting the same error while creating an element with: 

'Element docElement = (Element)doc;' 

I also used org.w3c.dom in front of it but it didn't work

Comment: Try first using `import org.w3c.dom.Element` if there is no clash.  Otherwise use the FQDN with `Element` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are importing class from wrong package than what you need for XML parsing, please refer the below code for importing class from right package.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = (Document) dBuilder.parse(xmlfile);
```